# GRU unit cell - Changing from LSTM to GRU

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, tikz-arrows, tikz-styles

I draw an LSTM unit cell in LaTeX this way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, fit, arrows.meta, shapes}

% Command \empt{var1}{var2} to avoid repetition
\newcommand{\empt}[2]{$#1^{\langle #2 \rangle}$}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        font=\sf \scriptsize,
        >=LaTeX,
        cell/.style={
            rectangle, 
            rounded corners=5mm, 
            draw,
            very thick,
        },
        operator/.style={
            circle,
            draw,
            inner sep=-0.5pt,
            minimum height =.2cm,
        },
        function/.style={
            ellipse,
            draw,
            inner sep=1pt
        },
        ct/.style={
            circle,
            draw,
            line width = .75pt,
            minimum width=1cm,
            inner sep=1pt,
        },
        gt/.style={
            rectangle,
            draw,
            minimum width=4mm,
            minimum height=3mm,
            inner sep=1pt
        },
        mylabel/.style={
            font=\scriptsize\sffamily
        },
        ArrowC1/.style={
            rounded corners=.25cm,
            thick,
        },
        ArrowC2/.style={
            rounded corners=.5cm,
            thick,
        },
    ]

    % Drawing starts here
    \node [cell, minimum height =4cm, minimum width=6cm] {}; 

    % Draw inputs named ibox#
    \node [gt] (ibox1) at (-2,-0.75) {$\sigma$};
    \node [gt] (ibox2) at (-1.5,-0.75) {$\sigma$};
    \node [gt, minimum width=1cm] (ibox3) at (-0.5,-0.75) {Tanh};
    \node [gt] (ibox4) at (0.5,-0.75) {$\sigma$};

   % Draw operators   named mux# , add# and func#
    \node [operator] (mux1) at (-2,1.5) {$\times$};
    \node [operator] (add1) at (-0.5,1.5) {+};
    \node [operator] (mux2) at (-0.5,0) {$\times$};
    \node [operator] (mux3) at (1.5,0) {$\times$};
    \node [function] (func1) at (1.5,0.75) {Tanh};

    % Draw External inputs, named as basis c,h,x
    \node[ct, label={[mylabel]Cell}] (c) at (-4,1.5) {\empt{c}{t-1}};
    \node[ct, label={[mylabel]Hidden}] (h) at (-4,-1.5) {\empt{h}{t-1}};
    \node[ct, label={[mylabel]left:Input}] (x) at (-2.5,-3) {\empt{x}{t}};

    % Draw External outputs, named as basis c2,h2,x2
    \node[ct, label={[mylabel]Cell}] (c2) at (4,1.5) {\empt{c}{t}};
    \node[ct, label={[mylabel]Hidden}] (h2) at (4,-1.5) {\empt{h}{t}};
    \node[ct, label={[mylabel]Output}] (x2) at (2.5,3) {\empt{h}{t}};
    
% Start connecting all.
    %Intersections and displacements are used. 
    % Drawing arrows    
    \draw [ArrowC1] (c) -- (mux1) -- (add1) -- (c2);

    % Inputs
    \draw [ArrowC2] (h) -| (ibox4);
    \draw [ArrowC1] (h -| ibox1)++(-0.5,0) -| (ibox1); 
    \draw [ArrowC1] (h -| ibox2)++(-0.5,0) -| (ibox2);
    \draw [ArrowC1] (h -| ibox3)++(-0.5,0) -| (ibox3);
    \draw [ArrowC1] (x) -- (x |- h)-| (ibox3);

    % Internal
    \draw [->, ArrowC2] (ibox1) -- (mux1);
    \draw [->, ArrowC2] (ibox2) |- (mux2);
    \draw [->, ArrowC2] (ibox3) -- (mux2);
    \draw [->, ArrowC2] (ibox4) |- (mux3);
    \draw [->, ArrowC2] (mux2) -- (add1);
    \draw [->, ArrowC1] (add1 -| func1)++(-0.5,0) -| (func1);
    \draw [->, ArrowC2] (func1) -- (mux3);

    %Outputs
    \draw [-, ArrowC2] (mux3) |- (h2);
    \draw (c2 -| x2) ++(0,-0.1) coordinate (i1);
    \draw [-, ArrowC2] (h2 -| x2)++(-0.5,0) -| (i1);
    \draw [-, ArrowC2] (i1)++(0,0.2) -- (x2);

    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Architecture of an LSTM unit.}
    \label{fig:lstm_architecture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

And I got the output:

[image]

Now, I need to change this scheme for a GRU (gated recurrent unit), but I'm not being able to change this code to do so. Can someone help me with this, if it is possible? It should look similar to this:

[image]

I'm really new to this and I really need some help